# Как отловить изменение текста в DatePicker

Tags: javafx

```
datePicker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

            }
        });
```

Делаю вот так, мало того что это не работает, да и если бы и работало, то скорее всего неправильно. Я хочу отловить событие в textField в DataPicker именно в реально времени, т. е. когда прям пишешь. Потому что есть такая вещь, что если я ,например, пишу в поле "аааа" то перемещая действие на другое компонент "аааа" в TextField исчезает. Я хочу чтобы например при записи "ааа" этот листенер сработал 3 раза, т.е. в реальном времени воспринимал изменение. Это возможно сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я хочу чтобы например при записи "ааа" этот листенер сработал 3 раза, т.е. в реальном времени воспринимал изменение.

Ваш код должен быть рабочим. Вероятно вы не к тому datePicker привязали слушатель.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                System.out.println(newValue);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(datePicker));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

При последовательном вводе "ааа" получаем вывод:

а

аа

ааа

Answer (score 0):

У объекта Node от которого унаследованы все элементы javafx есть ряд методов

- onKeyPressed
- onKeyReleased
- onKeyTyped

Все они реагируют на ввод с клавиатуры. Используйте их.

[javaDoc по методам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyPressedProperty)

Comment: Попробовал все в стиле:

Comment: DatePicker.getEditor().onKeyTyperProperty()

Comment: и другие.. ни один не реагирует

Comment: @Youlfey тогда дополните код в посте до минимально воспроизводимого примера